# What is the word for Sutak in the South? Are the practices different in different communities?

Tags: sutak

I have run across "sutak" may times at HSE and only today I realized it is similar to what South Indian Brahmins called "theetu".

Are these practices based on scripture?  Do different communities call it by different names?